# Intra-assignment delay in verilog

Tags: verilog

What is the difference between 
x=#5 a;   where a blocking statement is used

And  x<=#5 a;  where a non blocking statement is used

Answer (score 0):

If you've a blocking assignment statement it'll be executed in the order that's  specified in a sequential block. For example,

```
initial begin
x=#5 a;
y=#5 b;
end
```

The `a` is assigned to `x` at simulation time 5, while `b` is assigned to `y` at simulation time 10. Now consider nonblocking assignment statements with intra-assignment delays that follow in a sequential block:

```
initial begin
x<=#5 a;
y<=#5 b;
end
```

In the above case both `a` and `b` are  *concurrently* assigned to `x` and `y` at simulation time 5. In other words, non-blocking assignment statements don't block execution of other statements that follow in a sequential block. Or it can be said that the ordering of non-blocking assignment statements in a sequential block doesn't matter at all.